# Erratic query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am new to this site, but please don't hold it against me. I have only used it once.

Here is my dilemma: I have moderate SQL knowledge but am no expert. The query below was created by a consultant a long time ago.

On most mornings it takes a 1.5 hours to run because there is lots of data. BUT other mornings, it takes 4-6 hours. I have tried eliminating any jobs that are running. I am thoroughly confused as to what to try to find out what is causing this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

I have already broken this query into 2 queries, but any tips on ways to help boost performance would be greatly appreciated.

This query builds back our inventory transactions to find what our stock on hand value was at any given point in time.

```
SELECT     
    ITCO, ITIM, ITLOT, Time, ITWH, Qty, ITITCD,ITIREF, 
    SellPrice, SellCost,
    case 
        when Transaction_Cost is null 
        then Qty * (SELECT ITIACT 
                    FROM (Select Top 1 B.ITITDJ, B.ITIREF, B.ITIACT
                          From OMCXIT00 AS B 
                          Where A.ITCO = B.ITCO
                          AND A.ITWH = B.ITWH
                          AND A.ITIM = B.ITIM
                          AND A.ITLOT = B.ITLOT 
                          AND ((A.ITITDJ > B.ITITDJ) 
                               OR (A.ITITDJ = B.ITITDJ AND A.ITIREF <= B.ITIREF))
                          ORDER BY B.ITITDJ DESC, B.ITIREF DESC) as C) 
        else Transaction_Cost
    END AS Transaction_Cost, 
    case when ITITCD = 'S' then ' Shipped - Stock' else null end as TypeofSale,
    case when ititcd = 'S' then ITIREF else null end as OrderNumber
FROM  
    dbo.InvTransTable2 AS A
```

Here is the execution plan.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/evw9u.png
[image: Execution plan bottle neck on sort I think]

Here is the DTA but I am unsure how to read it since the recommedations are blank. Shouldn't that say "Create"?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAbq0.png

Comment: What does the execution plan look like? Is it the same on all days? (I don't know about SQL server, but e.g. on Oracle servers, symptoms like this might be caused by "Bind variable peeking" - Googling for SQL server bind variable peeking might give you some hints)

Comment: Looks like there is a bottle know of the sort.

Comment: You need to create an index on table `OMCXIT00` that corresponds to the filter and order by.

Comment: Do you have any indexes on your tables? Looks like you don't, or they're on the wrong columns, judging by the table scans in your execution plan.

Comment: Going to sound like a dumb question but how do I know what index to create? Do I create it based on the where clause or the joins?

Comment: You should be able to create indexes on the fields you are selecting, or even the fields in your where clause... indexes do create some overhead... but not bad.  When you have found the index which grants you the best performance, you could remove the un-necessary ones.

Comment: Try creating a covering index on `OMCXIT00` containing the following columns: `ITITDJ`, `ITIREF`, `ITIACT`, `ITCO`, `ITWH`, `ITIM`, `ITLOT`. For `ITITDJ` and `ITIREF`, set the sort order to `DESC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do match with  dbo.InvTransTable2, because of you are selected all records from it, so it will be left scanning records.

1. Make sure that you have clustered index on OMCXIT00, it looks like it is a heap, no clustered index.
   Make sure that clustered index is small, but has more distinct values in it.
2. If you have not many records OMCXIT00, it may be sufficient to create index with key ITCO and include following columns in include ( ITITDJ , ITIREF, ITWH,ITCO ,ITIM,ITLOT  )

Index creation example:

```
   CREATE INDEX IX_dbo_OMCXIT00 
                     ON OMCXIT00 ([ITCO])
                    INCLUDE ( ITITDJ , ITIREF)
```

1. If it does not help, then you need to see which columns in the predicates that you are searching for has more distinct values, and create index with key one or some of them and make sure reorder predicate order in where clause.

   ```
                     A.ITCO = B.ITCO
                     AND A.ITWH = B.ITWH
                     AND A.ITIM = B.ITIM
                     AND A.ITLOT = B.ITLOT
   ```

Comment: Not sure what too many items would be. There are ~4.5 million records.

Comment: How many records do you expect to return for each record in InvTransTable2 from OMCXIT00 and order it by ? If you get 1000 records to sort then it should fine, if more you might consider changing query based on the logic, for example if you have identity column, you can use MAX to get it, it would work faster than ordering subset of data.

Comment: Adding index still will improve it, it will not need to scan 4.5 millions records for each record in InvTransTable2 :)

Comment: I would expect the resulting table to have about 4 million records. I created the index  that  SchmitzIT had suggested but running an new Execution plan doesn't show it useing the new index.

Comment: Can you please post index definition.

Comment: Sorry FarFarak, I added a new index in the correct order as you said above of CREATE INDEX Index_XIT03
ON OMCXIT00 (ITCO, ITWH, ITIM, ITLOT, ITITDJ Desc, ITIREF DESC)            and now it appears to use that index, but the execution plan changed to <http://i.imgur.com/1whrb.png> I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Add ITIACT column which is being lookedup, to include, and it will do only index seek and should fly. CREATE INDEX Index_XIT03 ON OMCXIT00 (ITCO, ITWH, ITIM, ITLOT, ITITDJ Desc, ITIREF DESC) INCLUDE (ITIACT)

Comment: That was it!!! Thank you so much. I am going to go and try and create indexes for some of my larger tables.  Is there a down side to creating an index for everything in the DTA? I can't believe it is fixed. This has been such a thorn in my side and I really didn't want to throw money at the problem. Thank you!

Comment: The only downside of indexes, is slowness of inserts and updates, but if you have 1 index, it is not a problem, and depends on how slow it is, still with 4 millions records it should be down to milliseconds.

Comment: Insertes should not take long to run.

Answer (score 0):

besides adding indexes to change table scans for index seeks, ask to yourself: "do i really need this order by in this sql code?". if you dont neet this sorting, remove order by from your sql code. next, there is a good chance your code will be faster.

Comment: Yes I definitely need it. Thanks for responding though.